# Customize adaptive card in microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I am working on microsoft bot framework and I need to style the adaptive cards. But I am facing some challenges because in json file, I am unable to get the styling attribute. So, please suggest how I'll do this.

Comment: Which style you are looking for? Share your code please.

Answer (score 2):

the style of Adaptive Cards is defined by the App the card is shown in. If you are using Bot Framework for like MS Teams, MS Teams defines the look and feel of a card. In the JSON layout you can select color for a button in terms of "Danger" or "Normal" but the actual color is defined by the host.

If you are showing cards in your own app however, you can define the layout by changing the host config. (see here for details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/host-config)

Only the rendering app can change the styling of cards.

Hope that answers your question.